# How to use rails i18n in form text_field?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, locale

I have a text field in my form for user model.  While editing the record it has to show translated username in the text field for username column.

My text_field is like as follow

```
 <%=f.text_field :username, class: @user.errors[:username].any? ? "db_txtbox error" : "db_txtbox ", placeholder: "Enter Name"%>
```

and my tr.yml file is like as below.

```
 tr:
 activerecord:
    attributes:
            user:
          username:
              "user1": "oluşturmak"
```

I have tried the below. but its not working.

```
 <%=t (f.text_field :username, class: @user.errors[:username].any? ? "db_txtbox error" : "db_txtbox ", placeholder: "Enter Name")%>
```

Please guide me to fix the issue.

Comment: have you posted well formatted `tr.yml`? I can see formatting issues

Comment: i edited with original format which i have in my code

Comment: tr.yml file is not formatted. Please format it accordingly as like as en.yml file.

Comment: is your question still open?

Answer (score 0):

you could write:

```
<%= f.label :username %>
<%= f.text_field :username, ...
```

and

```
tr:
  helpers:
    label:
      user:
        username: "oluşturmak"
```

if you need attributes you could refactor your data:

```
tr:
  activerecord:
    attributes:
      user:
        username: "oluşturmak"
```

and then write something like: `User.human_attribute_name("username")`

also you could use `t` for get translation like: `t("activerecord.attributes.user.username")`